# Limit in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

Can someone help me to solve these two questions:

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{z \to 1} {1 \over {{z^2} - 1}}$$

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{z \to 1} {1 \over {{{(z - 1)}^3}}}$$

I don't know how to solve it because when I substitute the answer is undefined.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would try to explain what, specifically, you're having difficulty with.  This will help us write the best possible answers for you.

Comment: The title and tag ask about complex analysis.  In the study of complex functions we consider "poles" as specially nice singularities.

Comment: The OP seems to have a simple question about what happens with reciprocals of small numbers in $\mathbb{C}$. I think an answer describing neighborhoods of infinity would be quite useful. The lack of context is probably because the OP does not know enough to ask the right questions. They *did* show what they have tried: "when I substitute the answer is undefined." To me, this seems to be a case of someone pushing the boundaries of their knowledge, not someone avoiding the application of effort on their homework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you plug $z=1$ into the denominators of each of these fractions you get $0$.  Further, the denominators are polynomials, and all polynomials are *continuous*, so when you plug in a value of $z$ *close* to $1$ then the denominators will be *close* to zero.

What happens when you take the reciprocal of something very small (something very close to zero)?  The reciprocal of something very small is something very large.

As $z$ gets closer and closer to $1$, the denominators get closer and closer to $0$, and their reciprocals get larger and larger.  In the limit as $z \to 1$, the denominators reach $0$, so their reciprocals reach $\infty$.  Because we're dealing with complex numbers, this infinity is called *complex infinity*.